# split string number separated by dots to separate values with scala issue

Tags: java, scala

i have a string of number with dots seperating them, max 3 numbers, for example:

option1 - "1" (just one digit)

option2 - "1.2"

option3 - "1.2.4"

I want to split those numbers and have them stored in separate values, this was my solution:

```
val numbersRegex = """([^\.]+)\.?(\d)*\.?(\d)?""".r

def splitNumber(number: String): (Option[String], Option[String], Option[String]) = {
  val numbersRegex(first, second, third) = number
  (Option(first), Option(second), Option(third))
}
```

this worked good, but i found a problem for when I have number with more than one digit, like `"1.14.5"`

in this case I will get:

`(Some(1),Some(4),Some(5))`

which what I expect is

`(Some(1),Some(14),Some(5))`

someone know how should I fix it?

Comment: myString.split(".")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `split` function is much more concise.

```
scala> "1.14.5".split('.')
res2: Array[String] = Array(1, 14, 5)
```